# Create an OPC client with OpenScada UTGARD

Tags: java, client-server, opc

I´ve connected a PLC to Matrikon opc universal server, now my task is to connect the OPC server to a client based in Java. Im using jinterop libraries and i think utgard would be really useful for me but i dont really know how to start.

I can not find any example of usage with utgard and i dont know how to access to their own samples or documentation.

Answer (score 2):

we just finished a short tutorial to show how its used at https://openscada.atlassian.net/wiki/display/OP/HowToStartWithUtgard

Comment: Where is the source repo now? I need OPC library.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a custom Java application where you need to access OPC data, I would recommend using OPC UA, instead of the traditional OPC DA, for new development. UA is also natively available for Java - and has several other alternatives as well in practice.

OPC Foundation is providing the [Java stack](http://www.opcfoundation.org/Downloads.aspx?CM=1&CN=KEY&CI=285) for it's member's. But a full Java SDK, such as the [Prosys OPC UA Java SDK](http://www.prosysopc.com/opc-ua-java-sdk.php) will also provide you the necessary implementation of subscription and session management, etc.

There are some open source initiatives as well, but they are not on a very high level at the moment, so you will save the most by going to a commercial SDK (although I am saying this myself as a Prosys developer).

It doesn't contain SCADA UI components, though, so in that respect the OpenSCADA may be a better alternative, although it does not enable OPC UA.

Answer (score 1):

The examples and tests are in their Git tree here: http://git.openscada.org/?p=org.openscada.utgard.git;a=tree;f=org.openscada.opc.dcom.test/src/org/openscada/opc/dcom;hb=HEAD

There is a nicer browse interface on github: https://github.com/ctron/org.openscada.utgard

Comment: Where is this repo now?